# Self-Study Problem Solving ODE IVP Method Of Underdeterminded Coefficients

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, self-learning

I am stuck trying to solve the following second order differential equation:

$$
2y'' + 3y' - 2y = te^{-2t} 
$$

The problem is from [Paul's Online Notes](https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/IVPWithLaplace.aspx) in the Laplace Transform section, however in order to gain some practice I am also calculating the Method of Underdetermined Coefficients as well as the Variation of Parameters since for the IVP the solution should be unique and hence all three different methods should lead to the same solution.

My solution attempt:

(1) Normalize
\begin{align}
2y'' + 3y' - 2y &= te^{-2t} \\
\frac{1}{2}(2y'' + 3y' - 2y) &= \frac{1}{2}te^{-2t} \\
y'' + \frac{3}{2}y' - y &= \frac{1}{2}te^{-2t}
\end{align}

As the particular solution I try:

$$
y_p = (At + B)e^{-2t}
$$

and calculate the derivatives:
\begin{align}
y_p' &= -2(At + B)e^{-2t} + Ae^{-2t} \\
y_p'' &= 4(At + B)e^{-2t} - 2Ae^{-2t} - 2Ae^{-2t} = 4(At + B)e^{-2t} - 4Ae^{-2t} \\
\end{align}

thus:

\begin{align}
y_p'' + \frac{3}{2}y_p' - y_p &= 4(At + B)e^{-2t} - 4Ae^{-2t} + \frac{3}{2}(-2(At + B)e^{-2t} + Ae^{-2t}) - (At + B)e^{-2t} \\
&= e^{-2t}((At + B)(4 - 3 - 1) + A(-4 + \frac{3}{2})) \\
&= e^{-2t}((At + B)0 - A\frac{5}{2})) = t e^{-2t}\\
\end{align}

Now form here we can see that:

$$
0A = \frac{1}{2}
$$

which is not valid. I know that there is a solution, so where is my mistake? My guess is that I chose the wrong function for the particular solution, but I just followed the same pattern as [Paul's Online Notes Example 5](https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/UndeterminedCoefficients.aspx).

Comment: You must try $y_p = (At^2 + Bt+C)e^{-2t}$. Try to see why.

Comment: You could make the problem much simpler starting with $y=z\,e^{-2t}$ at the very beginning.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Can you post that as an answer, it got the solution out of it.

Comment: Did you understand why you need  $y_p = (At^2 + Bt+C)e^{-2t}$ ?

Comment: Actually I am not sure tbh. Is it because $e^{-2t}$ is in the general solution and also on the lhs of the equation? This is the only explanation I can come up with. Because in the example that I mention (not the one here) I calculated the general solution and it has two distict roots: 6 and -2 and the lhs of the ode is: $te^4t$ so in this example Paul uses: $y_p = At + B$ however the roots are different then in the exponent, which is not the case in the example presented here. Is that argument correct?

Comment: You got it ! Good luck in your studies.

Comment: Ok, perfect. Thank you very much! You were the first to respond and it was correct so pls turn your comment into an answer. Overall it took me a while, but solving theses problems with the different approaches is really helping in my understanding. Plus of course the help from many dedicated ppl here in this forum. It's truely amazing! Hope that I can be of help someday as well.

Comment: Don't worry ! I am glad to be able to help you. Cheers :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method of undetermined coefficients due to Lagrange, follows:

The homogeneous ODE has as solutions

$$
y_h = c_1 e^{\frac t2}+c_2 e^{-2t}
$$
now considering

$$
y_p = c_1(t) e^{\frac t2}+c_2(t) e^{-2t}
$$

after submitting to the complete ODE we have

$$
(2c_1''+5c_1')e^{\frac t2}+(-2c_2''+5c_2'+t)e^{-2t}=0
$$

now as $c_1,c_2$ are independent we can choose

$$
\cases{
2c_1''+5c_1'=0\\
-2c_2''+5c_2'+t=0
}
$$

thus we obtain as solutions

$$
\cases{
c_1 = -\frac 25e^{-5\frac t2}\mu_1+\mu_2\\
c_2 = -t\left(\frac{2}{25}+\frac{t}{10}\right)+e^{5\frac t2}\mu_3+\mu_4
}
$$

here $\mu_1,\cdots,\mu_4$ are integration constants. As we are choosing  particular solutions, we choose $\mu_1=\cdots=\mu_4=0$ and finally we have

$$
\cases{
c_1(t) = 0\\
c_2(t) = -t\left(\frac{2}{25}+\frac{t}{10}\right)
}
$$

and a particular solution is

$$
y_p = -t\left(\frac{2}{25}+\frac{t}{10}\right)e^{-2t}
$$